# Session data working local but not on remote

Tags: php

I am restricting page access with bellow code which works fine but when i upload it to remote server.the restricted can be accessed even if user is not logged in. Please help me.

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  if($_SESSION['uid']==true){
      if($_SESSION['roles']==3 or $_SESSION['roles']==1){
      }elseif($_SESSION['roles']==3){
      header('Location:../a/index.php?action=NOT Allowed');
      }elseif($_SESSION['roles']==4){
      header('Location:../b/index.php?action=NOT Allowed');
      }elseif($_SESSION['roles']==5){
      header('Location:../c/index.php?action=NOT Allowed');
      }
      }else{
        header('Location:../index.php');  
  }
?>
```

Comment: Check if `sessions` are set .. Try a `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: RFC 2616 mandates an absolute URI as value of the *Location* header field, i.e. it should include the scheme and the host name.

Comment: The branch where you redirect to `../a/index.php?action=NOT Allowed` will never be executed, because if `$_SESSION['roles']==3` then the first branch (where you tested `$_SESSION['roles']==3 or $_SESSION['roles']==1`) will be executed instead.

Comment: Please elaborate *can be accessed*. What are the relevant variable values? Where do the values come from?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code for dumping the values of your session variable

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```